# I am having trouble passing authentication parameters in the URL

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

These don't work in IE and the application that I am calling them from must be using IE - I can't change that.  Is there another way to pass within the URL?

https://[AccountSID:Token]@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts

https://api.twilio.com/2019-04-01/Accounts?AccountSid=[AccountSid]&AuthToken=[Token]

When I try these in an IE browser, it keeps popping up asking for the credentials.

Tried both formats

https://[AccountSID:Token]@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts

https://api.twilio.com/2019-04-01/Accounts?AccountSid=[AccountSid]&AuthToken=[Token]

When I try these in an IE browser, it keeps popping up asking for the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

We do not recommend that you make API calls to Twilio from the client-side regardless of which browser you are using. To make an API call from the client-side you need to include your credentials in the page somewhere, and if you do that you run the risk of a malicious user taking the credentials and abusing your account.

Instead, we recommend you run a server through which you can proxy requests to the Twilio API. That way, the server can store your credentials and no users can get hold of them. You can then make calls to the server through a form or an `XMLHttpRequest` from the browser.